# How do I pass value from my react component to my express API calls ?

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs

I'm not really sure how I should ask about that. I've an app with React/Redux/d3 on the client-side and Node/express on the server side (correct me is this description seems wrong). I would like to allow users to update the API client with for example a dropdown menu. I'm not looking for specific code here but more general pattern.

For exemple here is a part of my google analytics API call :

```
// query the data
var queryData = function(req, res) {
  // authorize the client (see code above)
  authorize(function() {
    // do the actual call to the google api
    analytics.data.ga.get({
      'auth': jwtClient,
      'ids': VIEW_ID,
      'metrics': 'ga:uniquePageviews',
      'dimensions': 'ga:pagePath',
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'yesterday',
      'sort': '-ga:uniquePageviews',
      'max-results': 10,
    }, function (err, response) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      // send the data to the client (i.e. browser)
      res.send(response);
    }); 
  });
}

module.exports = {
    queryData
};
```

Following the code above, I would like to have a drop-down menu with various `'start-date'` for example. Does my question is clear ? How do I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expressjs function can get request parameters from the request object "req"

```
 req.params.startDate
```

So you need to request your expressjs endpoint with the parameters need to make the code below variable and use the dynamic values.

```
 // query the data
 var queryData = function(req, res) {

    // req.params contains the parameters from the call to this expressjs function
    // Lets assume you send a "startDate" parameter
    var startDate = req.params.startDate

    // authorize the client (see code above)
    authorize(function() {
    // do the actual call to the google api
    analytics.data.ga.get({
      'auth': jwtClient,
      'ids': VIEW_ID,
      'metrics': 'ga:uniquePageviews',
      'dimensions': 'ga:pagePath',
      'start-date': startDate,         // Then use the parameter here
      'end-date': 'yesterday',
      'sort': '-ga:uniquePageviews',
      'max-results': 10,
    }, function (err, response) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      // send the data to the client (i.e. browser)
      res.send(response);
    }); 
  });
}
```